# kmeans in MATLAB : number of clusters > number of rows?

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm using the Statistics Toolbox function kmeans in MATLAB for the first time. I want to get the total euclidian distance to nearest centroid as an indicator of optimal k.
Here is my code :

```
clear all

N=10;

opts=statset('MaxIter',1000);

X=dlmread(['data.txt']);

crit=zeros(1,N);
for j=1:N
    [a,b,c]=kmeans(X,j,'Start','cluster','EmptyAction','drop','Options',opts);
        clear a b
        crit(j)=sum(c);
end

save(['crit_',VF,'_',num2str(i),'_limswvl1.mat'],'crit')
```

Well everything should go well except that I get this error for j = 6 :
    X must have more rows than the number of clusters.

I do not understand the problem since X has 54 rows, and no NaNs.
I tried using different EmptyAction options but it still won't work.

Any idea ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs since you use the `cluster` method to get initial centroids. From MATLAB documentation:

> 'cluster' - Perform preliminary clustering phase on random 10%
>                          subsample of X.  This preliminary phase is itself
>                          initialized using 'sample'.

So when `j=6`, it tries to divide 10% of data into 6 clusters, i.e. 10% of 54 ~ 5. Therefore, you get the error `X must have more rows than the number of clusters`.

To get around this problem, either choose the points randomly (`sample` method) or choose points uniformly (`uniform` method).

Comment: Your answer is really helpful. Kindly elaborate how I can choose points randomly, as these points are again passed to kmeans, and it will again generate an error